# JAXB Marshal exception: .Impl class nor any of its super class is not known to any of this context

Tags: java, jaxb

I am encountering a problem while marshalling my Java objects using JAXB.
When i run the web service as an independent application, it works fine.

When i Integrate it with my project, and use the generated Java classes,
while marshalling, I get an exception

> `RequestImpl` class nor any of its super class is not known to any of this context.

While generating my JAXB instance I use the following statement:

```
JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.eos.hotels.API.Request");
```

I have 2 separate xsds, one for `Request` and another for `Response`.

The generated java classes are stored in a folder structure as follows:

```
API->Request
API->Response
```

In both the above folders, an `ObjectFactory.java` is created and `jaxb.properties` is also there.

Also, inside each of the above mentioned folders, `impl` folder is created which has all `Impl` files, and inside this `impl` folder, `runtime` folder is created.

All the `xs:element` from XSD are created as interfaces, only the `Impls` are classes.
Also, there are no XML annotations in the generated java files.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Is this problem happening because of folder structure or because the XML annotations are not present?

I read on the internet that annotations if not present also are not a problem.

I have even tried to copy the generated impl classes in the same folder as `ObjectFactory.java`, but that also did not work.

Comment: How are you generating the code?  The `Impl` thing sounds more like JAXB1 than JAXB2.

Comment: I am using an xsd to create Java files. As I mentioned above, the folder in which Java files is created, also has the impl folder created inside it.

Comment: I asked *how*, not what.  How are you running `xjc`?  What version of JAXB are you using to do it?

Comment: Oh sorry!! i am using ant xjc task to generate java

Comment: Since Impls are generated, i guess its version1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the `JAxbContext`  I used the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxb = new DefaultJAXBContextImpl(packagename, ObjectFactory.class                 .getClassLoader());
```

Though I am not sure why, it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call toString method on your JAXBContext object. Because you are using JAXB1 classes it should display somethig like: com.eos.hotels.API.impl.runtime.DefaultJAXBContextImpl. If it's not - you probably don't have jaxb.properties file in com.eos.hotels.API package or you've deleted com.eos.hotels.API.impl.runtime package.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a JAXBContext on generated classes from multiple directories you need to include all the package names separated by a colon ':'.

```
 JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.package1:org.example.package2");
```

Comment: Yes, but when i include the impl package, I get the error saying the impl package does not have ObjectFactory.java

Comment: @Akshay - Are you using a JAXB 1 (JSR-31) or JAXB 2 (JSR-222) implementation?   The easiest way to confirm is if you have any annotations from `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package you are using JAXB 2.  Since you mention impl classes you may be using JAXB 1.

Comment: Ok, considering this is the case,and I am using Jaxb1. Hence the annotations are not generated, but this does not solve my problem.I am still not able to figure out, why am I getting the exception of Impl class not found in the context.Is ther some problem with package resolution.
P.S.: Please see in my question the folder structure that is created in my project

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, I am facing this issue even though both packages contain ObjectFactory can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

So you're using jaxb1, and generating your jaxb classes from 2 distinct XSD's, hopefully declaring two separate namespace URIs (otherwise that will mess up JAXB).

First, I would consider combining the two XSD's, and having a single namespace URI. You can still use the same package structure, or end up with a single one, but more importantly will end up with a single runtime folder.
Also, you will end up with a single ObjectFactory and that will prevent having to use FQCN (fully-qualified classnames) when using both ObjectFactory classes from the the same class (that would make your import statements usless, which is a trap that could be at play here also).

When you build you JAXBContext, make sure to list all the *root* packages (not the impl ones), and you should be good to go.

Try this and let us know what you get. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, i tried combining the xsds and generating the java.What happend was, the object factory had reference only  for the response objects(i had merged the response xsd in the request one) all the request objects were missing from object factory.
Also on checking my xsds i see that both have the same namespace uri :( How do i change that?

Comment: I have merged the xsds into one, generated the java, still the same problem :( Impl nor any of its superclass is known to this context. I have one more question, while creating the jaxb context, i am giving the path of the folder where the files are created. For instance: JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.eos.apis.Try");   Is this ok?

Comment: @Akshay : the JAXBContext should be given the paths to the PACKAGES (i.e. not including the class names) where the ObjectFactory reside. If multiple XSD's were used, you need to separate with a ":". See the example given in (the always excellent) Blaise's answer.

Comment: As i said in my last comment, i have merged the xsds. So, I have a single folder now, say 'Try' which has the ObjectFactory and other classes. Inside this package i have the impl folder. Now when I am creating the jaxb context like this: JAXBContext.newInstance("com.eos.apis.Try"), it is still iving me the "RequestImpl Class not found in this context" error.